# A generalization of Perron–Frobenius claim about $\lim _{{k\rightarrow \infty }}A^{k}$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A=(a_{ij})$ be an $n\times n$ positive matrix: $ a_{{ij}}>0$ for $1\leq i,j\leq n$. According to the statement of [Perron–Frobenius theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perron%E2%80%93Frobenius_theorem#Statement_of_the_Perron.E2.80.93Frobenius_theorem), one of the claims is
$$\lim _{{k\rightarrow \infty }}A^{k}/r^{k}=vw^{T}\,,\quad \tag{1}$$ 
where the left and right eigenvectors for A are normalized so that $w^Tv = 1$. The positive real number $r$ is called the Perron root.

The question is as follows. Equation $(1)$ can be used to calculate $\lim _{{k\rightarrow \infty }}A^{k}$. Let $\{A^{(k)}\}_{k=1}^\infty$ be a sequence of $n\times n$ positive matrices; i.e., $A^{(k)}=(a^{(k)}_{ij})$ such that $a^{(k)}_{{ij}}>0$ for $1\leq i,j\leq n$, $\forall k=1,2,\dots$. I wonder if there exists a generalization of Perron–Frobenius claim about $\lim _{{k\rightarrow \infty }}A^{k}$, as follows:
$$\lim _{{k\rightarrow \infty }}\, \prod_{h=1}^k A^{(h)}=?$$
Note that if $A^{(h)}=\dots=A^{(2)}=A^{(1)}=A$, $\forall h$, we reobtain the Perron–Frobenius claim about $\lim _{{k\rightarrow \infty }}A^{k}$.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not without hypotheses.  Let $M$ be a matrix with all positive entries.  Then so is $A^{(h)} = \exp ( c_h M)$, where $c_h>0$ and $\exp(T)$ denotes the matrix exponential 
$$\exp(T) = e^T = \sum_{n\ge0} T^n/n!$$  The fact we use about the matrix exponential is that $\exp((t+u)M)=\exp(tM)\exp(uM)$.
Now choose the $c_n$ such that $\lim_{k\to\infty} \sum_{h=1}^k c_h = c<\infty$. (Such as $c_n=2^{-n}$, say.) Then $$\prod_{h=1}^k A^{(h)} = e^{\sum_{h=1}^k c_h M} $$ which converges to $\exp( cM)$ as $k\to\infty$.  This limit matrix has full rank, and hence is not of Perron-Frobenius limit form.

The problem with this example is that the individual factor matrices $A^{(h)}$ are very close to the identity matrix, and although all their entries are positive, the off-diagonal ones are very close to 0.  A ham fisted way of preventing this is to require all the matrix entries in all the factor matrices $A^{(h)}$ to be *uniformly bounded* away from 0.